# Why is my TC not working when it should in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMetet and I am having a lot of difficulties in understanding how it works.
I created a TC to add an object to my system using Blaze meter. Then, I imported the TC in Jmeter.

### This TC fails when it should not (at least thats what I think) because whenever I use the system it works correctly:

[image]

This is the thread group if you need it to help me:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? AM I missing something? 
IMPORTANT: Should I be able to see my object added to the system if the TC passes?

Comment: You have a 403 Forbidden response. I think you want to authenticate there? Did you pass the correct credentials? Or other headers if are required?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I want to authenticate in that part and credentials are correct !

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) description:

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

If your script assumes authentication most probably it fails somewhere somehow due to missing or improperly working [correlation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), for example this `eedd968fe...` bit

[image]

looks utterly suspicious, most probably you need to replace it with a some form of dynamic parameter extracted from the previous request using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Normally the flow looks like:

1. Open login page
2. Identify and extract all dynamic parameters and save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Send the parameters along with credentials in the 2nd request

Check out [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables/) article for example challenge and solution

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I will try and do what you told me.

Comment: I did what the tutorial says and I my tc stil fails in a part ot should not and I get this in the log: - 2019-11-01 11:18:46,949 ERROR o.a.j.e.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: 'Set-Cookie: GX_CLIENT_ID=(*?)'
2019-11-01 11:18:46,956 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: ***************************NOT FOUND
2019-11-01 11:18:46,956 ERROR o.a.j.e.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: 'Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=(*?)'
2019-11-01 11:18:46,963 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: ***************************NOT FOUND

Comment: Now I managed my self to fix the error but it still does no show the values it should show